# PHP serialize string format

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, serialization

In MySQL (for wordpress) there is the following value in a post_metadata :

```
a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:7:"Payment";s:19:"percentage_complete";s:1:"5";}}
```

We do :

```
$value_percentage = array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'title' => 'Payment',
        'percentage_complete' => '15',
      ),
    );
$serializedData = serialize($value_percentage);
update_post_meta( $id, $field_percentage, $serializedData );
```

But in the DB there is :

```
s:78:"a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:7:"Payment";s:19:"percentage_complete";s:2:"15";}}";
```

How to avoid the `s:78:"` ?

We also tried the following :

```
$value_percentage['percentage_complete'] = '15';
```

but there is the `s:78:"` in the DB

Comment: try directly using the _$value_percentage_ variable.  `update_post_meta( $id, $field_percentage, $value_percentage );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [maybe serialize](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize) and [maybe_unserialize](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) function to store and pull data

maybe unserialize

```
$string = 'a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:7:"Payment";s:19:"percentage_complete";s:1:"5";}}';
echo '<pre>', print_r(maybe_unserialize($string), 1), '</pre>';
```

output is like this,

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [title] => Payment
            [percentage_complete] => 5
        )

)
```

maybe serialize

```
$value_percentage = array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'title' => 'Payment',
        'percentage_complete' => '15',
      ),
);
echo '<pre>', print_r(maybe_serialize($value_percentage), 1), '</pre>';
```

output is

`a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:7:"Payment";s:19:"percentage_complete";s:2:"15";}}`